Self study for btech course in computer science
I'm highly interested in computer science, but I will not be able to join any computer science course in my undergraduate due to some issues. So in order to get the knowledge and skill of a btech undergraduate, what would be the books and problems solving resources from which one can self-study to get all the necessary knowledge of a btech computer science degree? Please share the websites and books from where advanced theoretical problems and can be solved.

Most of the site regulars are not based in India, so it may take awhile, but I hope this gets an answer.  There are certainly plenty of people who find themselves in this situation!

"btech" isn't a common term where I'm from, so I suggest spelling out Bachelor of Technology if that's what it means. Beyond that, this is a bit broad. I'd imagine the list would be highly variable depending on the particular curriculum you're interested in. I don't think there's some simple list of, say, 5 books that gives you all the knowledge of any technology bachelor's degree. Can you find a course listing for your particular bachelor's degree and look at the required textbooks from that?

There's something called NPTEL. You can appear for exams for <1000 Rupees. I suggest you try it.
